# How to get a dropdown list with content of other content type

Tags: nodes

I have a content type trainer where i have the fields trainer_name, trainer_tel and trainer_email.

I have a second content type club where i want a field that is a dropdownlist with all the trainer names of content type trainer.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Entity Reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module..

Project page says

> Provides a field type that can reference arbitrary entities:
>
> A generic entity reference field
>
> Four widgets:
>
> Two implemented on top of the Options module (Select and
>   Radios/Checkboxes),
>
> Two autocomplete widgets (one with one text field per entry, one
>   tag-style with comma- separated entries in the same text field)
>
> Two formatters:
>
> A "Label" formatter, with optional link that displays the label of the
>   referenced entity (the node title, the user name, etc.)
>
> A "Rendered entity" formatter, that renders the references entity
>   using a configurable view mode
>
> Integration with Views (for both forward and backward references)
>
> Integration with Entity Metadata (and as a consequence with Search API
>   and the like)
>
> Integration with Devel generate
>
> Integration with Feeds and Migrate (>= 2.3) for painless data import

Comment: Thx, this was what i needed.

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) If one of the answers above fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716